# How to convert a String to Integer or Float

Tags: ruby

I have a text field where the user can enter a number, and I want to be able to convert the string to an integer or float based on the user input. Is there an easy way to do that in Ruby?

For example:

```
User Input: "123"  -> Output: 123
User Input: "123.99" -> Output: 123.99
```

Comment: You want an integer for `"123"` and a float for `"123.99"`?

Comment: You might want to look in to why you want to do this? If a float is present, them maths will run and return a float (e.g. `1/2` returns `0` but `1.0/2` returns `0.5`. If the reason you want to have both types is to display an integer at the end (e.g. so the user doesn't see `1.0`) you might want to look into a method which renders the number as expected, and always convert your input to a float.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question like this we'd like to see evidence of your effort, usually as the minimal code demonstrating the problem you're having. Without that it looks like you didn't try and you want us to solve the problem for you. "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve]" go into this, along with http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: This is a common programming exercise. using module operator you extract the float point part and if it is greater than 0, it is considered a float number. then you do `.to_f`

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
def to_float_or_int(string)
  throw "error" unless string && string.length > 0
  return string.to_f if string.include?('.') || string.include?(',')
  string.to_i
end
```

The first line ensures that you always get a result based on the input. If you remove that an empty string will yield 0 instead of an error.

Comment: How about `to_float_or_int('1a') # => 1` or `to_float_or_int(' ') # => 0`?

Comment: No need to check for comma because you discard the information anyway : `'1,23'.to_f => 1`

Comment: Not all LOCALE settings use `.` as a fractional indicator. Depending on where someone is in the world `1,23` would be appropriate and `1,23.to_f` would be equivalent to a US-based `1.23`.

Comment: @theTinMan : never though about that. Do you know which locale is used? `LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8" ruby -e "puts '2,1'.to_f"` returns `2.0`

Comment: Also, `to_float_or_int("1a.")` is `1.0` where you'd probably want `1` for consistency.

Answer (score 8):

Use `to_i` or `to_f` on the string

```
irb(main):001:0> "13".to_i
=> 13
irb(main):002:0> "13".to_f
=> 13.0
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a common exercise. There might be more elegant ways to do this but this is the simplest one liner I came with.

```
def to_number(value)
  return if value.blank?
  (value.to_f % 1) > 0 ? value.to_f : value.to_i
end
```

Have in mind that mod operator is not fully precise. But for this case it should work for any stringified number.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Ruby 2.6, the global [`Integer()`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) and [`Float()`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Float) conversion methods have an `exception` argument that you can utilize to easily chain both methods:

```
def to_number(value)
  Integer(value, exception: false) || Float(value, exception: false)
end
```

```
n = to_number('123')
#=> 123
n.class
#=> Integer

n = to_number('123.99')
#=> 123.99
n.class
#=> Float

n = to_number('not a number')
#=> nil
n.class
#=> NilClass
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to avoid showing decimals when the input looks like an Integer, you could convert your input to a Float and use `'%g'` to display the number.

You might get unexpected behaviour or have to write some logic to check if your Numeric is a Float or an Integer otherwise.

```
def display_number(input)
  '%g' % Float(input)
end

puts display_number("1")
puts display_number(2)
puts display_number("1.23")
puts display_number(2.3456)
puts display_number(Math::PI)
puts display_number("not a number")

# => 1
# 2
# 1.23
# 2.3456
# 3.14159
# convert_to_int_or_float.rb:2:in `Float': invalid value for Float(): "not a number" (ArgumentError)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will extend String with two new methods but you just have to call `#to_numeric` on any string and it will return either a float or an int accordingly.

```
class String
  def numeric_string?
    Float(self) != nil rescue false
  end

  def to_numeric
    if self.numeric_string?
      if self.index('.')
        return self.to_f
      else
        return self.to_i
      end
    end
  end
end

['2.0', '15', '4500.1234', '111.234'].each do |str|
  puts str.to_numeric
end

# 2.0
# 15
# 4500.1234
# 111.234
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_f` function with `round` to change the string into float with exact decimal places. Example, I'm print the text about frequency value in .pdf file. The original data is in `string`.

```
text "#{(@qsos.frequency.to_f).round(3)} MHz"
```

This will result, the original text such `7.13500` will convert into `7.135`. If we try to `round` the value directly, it will return error as it is in `string`. So, we need to convert it into float first before we determine the decimal places.

Comment: HAM radio related. Tu de F5UKW

Comment: Yes @Toucouleur. Regardsz 9W2ZOW.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this for a case where I wanted to find differences between an imported data structure and a data structure generated by Ruby code, where the imported data is read as an int whenever the value can be represented as an int

I ended up going with this:

```
class String
    def to_num; to_i == to_f ? to_i : to_f; end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

I'd use:

```
def convert(input)
  [:Integer, :Float].each do |m| 
    begin
      return Kernel.method(m).call(input)
    rescue ArgumentError
    end
  end
  nil
end

convert('') # => nil
convert(' ') # => nil
convert('1') # => 1
convert('1.0') # => 1.0
convert('.01') # => 0.01
```

How does it work?

`Integer()` and `Float()` are methods in the Kernel class, so

```
Kernel.method(m)
```

returns the method object, allowing `call` to send the `input` value to it. If it succeeds the returned value is returned and the `each` loop terminates. If it explodes `rescue ArgumentError` traps it and the `each` loop continues. If the loop ends without being short-circuited by `return` then `nil` gets returned by Ruby.

Comment: Isn't it overly complex? Wouldn't `Integer(input) rescue Float(input) rescue nil` just do?

Comment: also `convert(1.23)` returns `1`, which might not be expected.

Comment: Inline `rescue` doesn't catch the same thing as `rescue ArgumentError`.

Comment: On my system `convert('1.23')` returns `1.23` correctly.

Comment: Yes, it works fine with a String as input, but not with a Float.

Comment: The OP is passing in the contents of a text field, so a string input is correct.

Comment: If input is an already defined String, what other Exception could be raised by Integer(input)?

Comment: The exception is an ArgumentError. Underlying code could return something else. Inline `rescue` would mask that exception resulting in very hard to diagnose errors. In general inline `rescue` is discouraged as a result of that.

Comment: I know inline `rescue` can be dangerous, I just cannot come up with an example in this specific case.

Comment: `convert(input)` seems too broad a name for something that converts a Float to an Integer. Anyway, enough with the nitpick, and thanks for the insightful answers!

Comment: As you know, `Kernel` is included by `Object`, so it's available to every object. You therefore can just write `return method(m).call(input)`. Alternatively, `return send(m, input)`.