# How to check if a value is valid input for Integer(), Float() or Rational()?

Tags: ruby, type-conversion

This is loosely based on "[How to convert a String to Integer or Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40721079/ruby-string-to-integer-or-float)".

If I wanted to convert a numerical string input to its "most appropriate type" using Ruby's built-in conversion mechanics, I could do something like this:

```
def convert(input)
  value = Integer(input) rescue nil
  value ||= Float(input) rescue nil
  value ||= Rational(input) rescue nil
  value
end

convert('1')     #=> 1
convert('1_000') #=> 1000
convert('0xff')  #=> 255
convert('0.5')   #=> 0.5
convert('1e2')   #=> 100.0
convert('1/2')   #=> (1/2)
convert('foo')   #=> nil
```

But this brute-force method-calling looks dirty. Is there a more elegant way to approach this? Can I *check* whether a value is a valid input for `Integer()`, `Float()` or `Rational()` so I could call these methods in a more controlled manner?

Comment: I'm having a hard time envisioning when you would need this. Is this user-supplied input? Are you evaluating Ruby code? What is the intended use of the converted value?

Comment: @meagar to be honest, I don't have an actual use case. Maybe a calculator that evaluates `1 + 2` to `3` and `1/2 + 2/3` to `7/6`.

Comment: Thinking about this, `String#to_i`, `to_f` and `to_r` should just return `nil` instead of `0`, `0.0` and `(0/1)` if a value cannot be parsed. This would allow for a non-exceptional, non-ambiguous check and you could still provide your own default easily via `str.to_i || 0`. It's probably a little to late to fix that.

Comment: Similarly, I've wondered why `Integer(str)` does not return `nil`, rather than raising an exception, when `str` does not represent an integer. (Same with `Float`, etc.) I expect there's a good reason. Can anyone elucidate? btw, I think what you have is best, possibly in the form of a `Kernel` method `Numeric`.

Comment: I've opened a [feature request](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12968) to allow `Integer()`, `Float()` etc. to take an optional block that provides a fallback value.

Comment: Update a request according to my comment, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a trailing rescue makes me cringe as it can obscure problems with the underlying code since it traps Exception not ArgumentError, which is what the failed attempted conversions would raise. This isn't as concise but it'd handle the appropriate exception:

```
def convert(input)
  value = begin
            Integer(input)
          rescue ArgumentError
            nil
          end

  value ||= begin
              Float(input)
            rescue ArgumentError
              nil
            end

  value ||= begin
              Rational(input)
            rescue ArgumentError
              nil
            end

  value
end

convert('1')     # => 1
convert('1_000') # => 1000
convert('0xff')  # => 255
convert('0.5')   # => 0.5
convert('1e2')   # => 100.0
convert('1/2')   # => (1/2)
convert('foo')   # => nil
```

After thinking about it a bit it seems like that can be DRY'd down to:

```
def convert(input)
  [:Integer, :Float, :Rational].each do |m| 
    begin
      return Kernel.method(m).call(input)
    rescue ArgumentError
    end
  end
  nil
end

convert('1')     # => 1
convert('1_000') # => 1000
convert('0xff')  # => 255
convert('0.5')   # => 0.5
convert('1e2')   # => 100.0
convert('1/2')   # => (1/2)
convert('foo')   # => nil
```

---

As pointed out by Jörn, the above wasn't a good example. I was using Kernel to get at `Integer()`, `Float()` and `Rational` because that's where they're defined, but really Object was the place to look since it inherits from Kernel.

And it'd been one of those days when I knew there was a good way to call the method indirectly, but `call` was sticking in my mind, not [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Object.html#method-i-send) as Stephan pointed out. So, here's a cleaner way of doing it, starting with:

```
  return Object.send(m, input)
```

But, that could be reduced to:

```
 return send(m, input)
```

resulting in:

```
def convert(input)
  [:Integer, :Float, :Rational].each do |m| 
    begin
      return send(m, input)
    rescue ArgumentError
    end
  end
  nil
end

convert('1')     # => 1
convert('1_000') # => 1000
convert('0xff')  # => 255
convert('0.5')   # => 0.5
convert('1e2')   # => 100.0
convert('1/2')   # => (1/2)
convert('foo')   # => nil
```

Comment: What is the reason for using `Object#method` in conjunction with `Method#call` instead of just `Object#public_send`? And why call it on `Kernel` instead of simply `self` like you do in the non-metaprogrammed version? I think that's very confusing, the only reason that works at all, is because `Kernel` is an instance of `Module`, which is a subclass of `Object`, which `include`s `Kernel` and thus inherits those methods. That's a very indirect way of calling them.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I second that, but it actually has to be `send(m, input)`, because these are private methods.

Comment: I wrote it this way because my brain wasn't working. It'd been a long day. :-) I'll see if I can make it less confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Since for some reason you prefer `"0.3"` to be converted to `3e-1` rather than to `3/10`, this might be done in more explicit manner. After all, under the hood, there is the same recognition mechanism in ruby parser:

```
def convert input
  raise unless String === input && input[/\A_|_\z|__/].nil?
  input = input.strip.delete('_')
  case input
  when /\A-?\d+\z/ then Integer(input)
  when /\A-?0x[\da-f]+\z/i then Integer(input)
  when /\A-?(\d*\.)?\d+(e-?\d+)?\z/i then Float(input)
  when /\A-?(\d*\.)?\d+(e-?\d+)?\/\d+\z/i then Rational(input)
  end
end
```

And that works as expected :)

Comment: The code is not quite right, e.g. it tries to parse `'0.5'` as an Integer.

Comment: @Stefan excuse me?

Comment: `convert('0.5')` raises an `ArgumentError` – `invalid value for Integer(): "0.5"`. This is because `/-?\d+/` matches `'0.5'`. You have to re-arrange your `when`'s or use anchors.

Comment: Still doesn't work for `'1e2'` and `'1/2'`, but +1 anyway, this is a viable alternative. Note that `delete('_')` allows for input values that would have been rejected otherwise, e.g. `'_0'`, `'0_'`, or `'0__0'`.

Comment: @Stefan fixed all three glitches.

Comment: That shows this approach's downside: you effectively have to re-implement Ruby's number parsing.

Comment: @Stefan yes, but more responsibility gives more power here: I am to handle corner cases as expected, not as `std` thinks. And, BTW, this approach is safe against monkey patching with weird `SafeConvert`s :)

Comment: My example was misleading. I never meant to monkey patch Kernel, just method overriding for a selective class.

Answer (score 2):

Piggybacking on [the Tin Man's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40725499/477037), one could use a module to override `Kernel`'s default behavior:

```
module SafeConvert
  def Integer(*)  ; super ; rescue ArgumentError ; end
  def Float(*)    ; super ; rescue ArgumentError ; end
  def Rational(*) ; super ; rescue ArgumentError ; end
end
```

This would shorten the code to:

```
class Helper
  include SafeConvert

  def convert(input)
    Integer(input) || Float(input) || Rational(input)
  end
end
```

Comment: Nicely done. Much cleaner. And I didn't know an inline `rescue` could be told what exception to catch; It's been a while since I looked at it's documentation.

Comment: @theTinMan it's a regular `rescue`, note the `;`

Comment: Yep. Sigh. I'm going to take a much needed nap. :-)