# In ruby , How do you check if an input is a float or a string ?

Tags: ruby, string, input

I am asking the user to enter a number ( Price for something).
How do I proceed with the code if it is a number.

If the input is not a valid number, then I want to display an error code saying " please input a numerical value"

Similarly, how do I check if it is a string. the user has to choose from 5 letters, A-E. If they input anything other than a string, I want to display an error message.  I haven't learnt how to create groups of values in a variable, example ,

letters = {A,B,C,D,E}. 
ideally, I would like to search through letters, and if it is not something that the user inputed, then i want to print an error message.

However, I have only learned up to conditional statements so far. I don't want there to be loops.

Comment: You've asked two questions in one, please only ask one question per post.

Comment: You can use regexp to check for integers(numbers) google regexp for ruby . once u get that working we can help with second question. If u try n cant get it to work show what u tried and ill help u from there but as dude above says one question at a time is best way to go man

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722804/how-to-check-if-a-value-is-valid-input-for-integer-float-or-rational