# Is there a standard way to convert a Ruby string to either an integer or float depending on the string?

Tags: ruby, activesupport

Is there a function in the standard Ruby library or in ActiveSupport which works like this?

```
f("1.5") == 1.5
f("1") == 1 # Not 1.0
f("1.0") == 1.0
```

Of course I can easily write my own, but wanted to ask in case I overlooked a built-in solution.

Comment: probably not, other than `eval`.

Comment: ```Integer(value, exception: false) || Float(value, exception: false)``` works fine, I've added that variant as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77287707/477037) to the linked question.

Comment: BTW, assuming that you want to do calculations: working with objects that have varying classes because of user input can be quite tricky and full of surprises. It might be easier to work with a consistent representation internally (e.g. float, rational, big decimal) and only convert / decorate the result as needed.

Comment: @Stefan Yes, I am aware that in many cases it's a problem.